# local database path in Parse sdk for android

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-sqlite

I'm using Parse SDK for Android for a student management app. I store data locally sometimes using `pinInBackground()` method. I'm excited to know where the data is being saved in the android system. Does anyone know?

Comment: \Phone(sd card-0)\Android\data\ one folder with ur package name with app name ... check over there .. ( eg: com.android.contacts )